# Using RegExp With Replace and Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I am running a RegExp on a user input to test for capitals of 3 or more in a row. I have a loop that finds the RegExp and then adds it to an array. Another loop that creates a new array. When I run the .replace it seems that that array isn't being looped over.

```
var abbrBracket = /\([A-Z]{3,30}\)/g;   
var abbrBracketArr = [];
var a;
while (a = abbrBracket.exec(nonCode)) {
    abbrBracketArr.push(a[0]);
}

var capFoundInArr = /[A-Z]{3,30}/g;
var abbrBracketArrRemove = [];
var b;
while (b = capFoundInArr.exec(abbrBracketArr)) {
    abbrBracketArrRemove.push('(<abbr>' + b[0] + '</abbr>)');
}

for(var c = 0; c < abbrBracketArrRemove.length; c++){
    nonCode = document.getElementById('cleanse').innerHTML; 
    //nonCode = nonCode.replace(new RegExp(/\([A-Z]{3,30}\)/), abbrBracketArrRemove[c]);
    nonCode = nonCode.replace(new RegExp(abbrBracketArr[c]), abbrBracketArrRemove[c]);
    document.getElementById('cleanse').innerHTML = nonCode;
}
```

The results show if there are two (or more) of the same abbreviations, the first is executed multiple times the next is skipped.

Saying that, I am using the exact same code to run a second query for replace and I am not getting this error.

```
    var abbrNoBracket = /\s[A-Z]{3,30}/g;   
var abbrNoBracketArr = [];
var d;
while (d = abbrNoBracket.exec(nonCode)) {
    abbrNoBracketArr.push(d[0]);
}

var abbrNoBracketArrRemove = [];
var e;
while (e = capFoundInArr.exec(abbrNoBracketArr)) {
    abbrNoBracketArrRemove.push(' <abbr title="">' + e[0] + '</abbr>');
}

for(var f = 0; f < abbrNoBracketArrRemove.length; f++){
    nonCode = document.getElementById('cleanse').innerHTML; 
    nonCode = nonCode.replace(new RegExp(abbrNoBracketArr[f]), abbrNoBracketArrRemove[f]);
    document.getElementById('cleanse').innerHTML = nonCode;
}
```

In the first block, you can see I commented out a line, if I use the RegExp instead of the array. It works. Curious, why this would work for one, but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error, which was very obvious after a good nights sleep.

I called a new RegExp on the array. Once I removed that, everything worked as it should.

```
for(var c = 0; c < abbrBracketArrRemove.length; c++){
nonCode = document.getElementById('cleanse').innerHTML;
//mistake
//nonCode = nonCode.replace(new RegExp(abbrNoBracketArr[f]), abbrNoBracketArrRemove[f]);
//corrected
nonCode = nonCode.replace(abbrBracketArr[c], abbrBracketArrRemove[c]);
document.getElementById('cleanse').innerHTML = nonCode;
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone else.